# Passing a partial model to a Display Template in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a view model derived from a base view model. The base VM has two properties, bool IsDisplayable & int MyValue.

I would like to create a display template that would take those two values and either display MyValue or not depending on the value of IsDisplayable.

This pair of values is part of all my view models and I would like to use one Display Template for all my views that use models derived from my base model.

My question is how would I pass this part of each view model to my Display Template?

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MyValue,"MyDisplayTemplate")
```

My Display Template:

```
@model WhatModelGoesHere
@if (Model.IsDisplayable)
{
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MyValue)
</td>
}
```

The difficulty is trying to make the display template generic enough to work with any of my view models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you create a common base class for other models to inherit.

Put the two fields IsDisplayable and MyValue that you need to display in the public template in the common base class, so that you only need to reference the `common base class` in the template.

And I suggest you use `partial view` to implement Display Template.

Common base class:

```
 public class GenricModel
{
    public bool IsDisplayable { get; set; }
    public int MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

View Model to inhert common base class:

```
  public class ViewModel1 : GenricModel
{
    public int Id { get; set;    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In the view to show ViewModel1 data, you can use `@Html.Partial("_TemplateView", item)` to call Display Template, here is an example based on ViewModel1：

```html
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication_core.Models.ViewModel1>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<table  class="table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Id
        </th>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            MyValue
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Id
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Name
            </td>
             @Html.Partial("_TemplateView", item)
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Then, create a partial view named `_TemplateView.cshtml` in Views folder.

Generally speaking, partial views are created under `Views/Shared` path in the project, you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1#partial-view-discovery).

```html
@model WebApplication_core.Models.GenricModel

@if (Model.IsDisplayable)
{
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.MyValue)
    </td>
}
```

[image]

Comment: So you are suggesting a strategy of using a partial view rather than a display template in this situation?

Comment: @JohnS,yes, I recommend that you use the partial view as above, partial view is more suitable for your needs.